# How to force div to appear after stretched div

Tags: css, html

html order is generated from template.
Sample output is below.

Elements in each row have fixed positions and sizes. This is implemented using 
row div containing field div with absolute position.

Description element is defined as

```
<div class='row' style='height:0.5cm;'>
    <div class='field' style='left:2.24cm;width:9.79cm;height:0.4cm'>RAM 16 GB - SSD 256 GB - DVD SuperMulti - GF GT 730M / HD Graphics 530 - GigE - Windows 7 Professional 64-bit Edition / Windows 10 Pro 64-bit Edition downgrade - pre-installed: Windows 7</div>
</div>
```

Sometimes item description is long and should wrap into multiple lines. For this I tried to remove heights from divs by using

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='field' style='left:2.24cm;width:9.79cm'>RAM 16 GB - SSD 256 GB - DVD SuperMulti - GF GT 730M / HD Graphics 530 - GigE - Windows 7 Professional 64-bit Edition / Windows 10 Pro 64-bit Edition downgrade - pre-installed: Windows 7</div>
</div>
```

Next row does not move down automatically. First row item description overwrites next row item name:

[image: overlap]

How to fix this so that next row appers after variable height description ?
Using hard-coded bigger heights like

```
<div class='row' style='height:1.5cm;'>
    <div class='field' style='left:2.24cm;width:9.79cm;height:1.4cm'>RAM 16 GB - SSD 256 GB - DVD SuperMulti - GF GT 730M / HD Graphics 530 - GigE - Windows 7 Professional 64-bit Edition / Windows 10 Pro 64-bit Edition downgrade - pre-installed: Windows 7</div>
</div>
```

Fixes the issue but it is fdifficult to calculate correct height since it depends on div content, width, font sizes etc and there are multiple columns in row
How to force browser to render this properly ?
html5, ASP.NET MVC4 and Razor views are used.

**Update**

Expected result can produced using hard coded heights

```
<div class='row' style='height:1.5cm;'>
    <div class='field' style='left:2.24cm;width:9.79cm;height:1.4cm'>
```

and is

[image: expected]

**Update 2 **

I tried to use relative position and min-height as recommended in answer using code below. This causes every field to apper in separate row. How to fix this so that multiple fields can appear nearly in same row like with absolute positioning ?

If style below is changed to

```
    .horizontalline, .field {
        position: absolute;
    }
```

fields appear poperly but strech causes overlap.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .row {
            position: relative;
            clear: both;
        }

        .field {
            overflow: hidden;
            word-break: break-all;
        }

        .horizontalline {
            font-size: 1pt;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
        }

        .horizontalline, .field {
            position: relative;
        }

        .horizontalline {
            border-bottom-style: none !important;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class='row' style='min-height:0.05cm;'>
        <div class='horizontalline' style='left:1.11cm;width:19.05cm;height:0.00cm;border-color:#C0C0C0;'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
        <div class='field' style='left:1.26cm;width:0.71cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;color:#000000;'>         1</div>
    </div><div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
        <div class='field' style='left:2.05cm;width:8.47cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;color:#000000;'>HP ProDesk 490 G3 - Micro tower - 1 x Core i7 6700</div>
    </div><div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
        <div class='field' style='left:10.58cm;width:1.68cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;text-align:right;color:#000000;'>31.12.2015</div>
    </div><div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
        <div class='field' style='left:12.24cm;width:0.79cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;text-align:right;color:#000000;'>1</div>
    </div><div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
        <div class='field' style='left:13.08cm;width:1.08cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;color:#000000;'>tk</div>
    </div>
    <div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
        <div class='field' style='left:14.32cm;width:1.26cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;color:#000000;'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
    </div>
    <div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
        <div class='field' style='left:16.61cm;width:1.42cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;text-align:right;color:#000000;'>1189</div>
    </div>
    <div class='row' style='min-height:0.42cm;'>
        <div class='field' style='left:17.79cm;width:2.00cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;font-weight:bold;text-align:right;color:#000000;'>1189</div>

    </div>
    <div class='row' style='min-height:0.51cm;'>
        <div class='field' style='left:2.24cm;width:9.79cm;min-height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;color:#000000;'>RAM 16 GB - SSD 256 GB - DVD SuperMulti - GF GT 730M / HD Graphics 530 - GigE - Windows 7 Professional 64-bit Edition / Windows 10 Pro 64-bit Edition downgrade - pre-installed: Windows 7</div>

    </div>

    <div class='row' style='min-height:0.05cm;'>
        <div class='horizontalline' style='left:1.11cm;width:19.05cm;height:0.00cm;border-color:#C0C0C0;'></div>

    </div>
    <div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
        <div class='field' style='left:1.26cm;width:0.71cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;color:#000000;'>         2</div>


    </div><div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
        <div class='field' style='left:2.05cm;width:8.47cm;min-height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;color:#000000;'>24x7 monitor: LG 32SL5B</div>


    </div><div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
        <div class='field' style='left:10.58cm;width:1.68cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;text-align:right;color:#000000;'>29.12.2015</div>


    </div><div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
        <div class='field' style='left:12.24cm;width:0.79cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;text-align:right;color:#000000;'>3</div>


    </div><div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
        <div class='field' style='left:13.08cm;width:1.08cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;color:#000000;'>tk</div>

    </div>
    <div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
        <div class='field' style='left:14.32cm;width:1.26cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;color:#000000;'>878,79</div>

    </div>
    <div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>

    </div>
    <div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
        <div class='field' style='left:16.61cm;width:1.42cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;text-align:right;color:#000000;'>580</div>

    </div>
    <div class='row' style='min-height:0.42cm;'>
        <div class='field' style='left:17.79cm;width:2.00cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;font-weight:bold;text-align:right;color:#000000;'>1740</div>

    </div>
    <div class='row' style='min-height:0.51cm;'>
        <div class='field' style='left:2.24cm;width:9.79cm;min-height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;color:#000000;'>450cd/m2, HDMI / DP / DVI / RGB / RJ45 /etc, 24/7 Operation, laos</div>

    </div>
    <div class='row' style='min-height:0.05cm;'>
        <div class='horizontalline' style='left:1.11cm;width:19.05cm;height:0.00cm;border-color:#C0C0C0;'></div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Output is:

[image: s]

Comment: As far as I can see the problem is in `position:absolute` of `.field`. But removing it breaks the layout. So, could you please add an image or describe how it should look.

Comment: your expected result? can you share

Comment: Why are you using positing in the first place? I'm not seeing the point. Also your `.row` elements need to be wrapped in another element, which would be a container.

Comment: @devpro I updated question and added expected result. Order layout is created using report designer which creates fixed positions and sizes for row. Absolute position should used to show this layout in html. However description element should strech automatically for long descriptions.

Comment: @SergiyT. I updated question and added expected result

Comment: So basically what you're trying to achieve is a sort of table. Perhaps you should  make it a table. So rows will grow to accomodate content.

Comment: Alright solution provided

Comment: @SergiyT. Existing templates containing absolute positioned fields should used. Fields are positioned in any position, it is difficult to create table layout form them. I tried to use relative position and min-height but this causes every field to appear in separate row. How to this this ? I updated question with new testcase

Comment: @SergiyT. I posted this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34457784/how-to-put-elements-to-same-row  How to fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

**Your HTML:**

```
<div class='row' >
        <div class='field'></div>
        <div class='field' >
            HP ProDesk 490 G3 - Micro tower - 1 x Core i7 6700
        </div>
        <div class='field'>tk</div>
        <div class='field' >1189</div>
        <div class='field'>1189</div>
    </div>


    <div class='row' >
        <div class='field'>RAM 16 GB - SSD 256 GB - DVD SuperMulti - GF GT 730M / HD Graphics 530 - GigE - Windows 7 Professional 64-bit Edition / Windows 10 Pro 64-bit Edition downgrade - pre-installed: Windows 7</div>
    </div>

    <div class='row' >
        <div class='horizontalline' ></div>

    </div>
    <div class='row' >
        <div class='field'>2</div>
        <div class='field' >24x7 monitor: LG 32SL5B</div>

    </div>
```

**Your CSS:**

```
<style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

.row {            
    clear: both;            
    width: 100%;
}

.field {
    width: 20%;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    font-size: 10pt;
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This assumes that every field width is 20%. Actually field dimension and positions are specified in GUI report designer using absolute coordinates. So this cannot used

Comment: U must need to fixed width otherwise bootstrap is an option

Comment: Report layouts are already created by GUI desingers in customer sites. Application must use them. It is not possible to change every customer designed layout. Mvc4 application which generates printable html from existing layouts shoud created. It tried to use relative position like in your answer but fields are now in separate rows. How to tfix this ? I updated question with new testcase.

Comment: Alright than in current html we need to play with css class more for specific div well I try my best without knowing the scenrio nice to meet u

Comment: New testcase in question should work. Why it places every field in separate row, maybe there is simple fix for this ?

Comment: I posted this as separate question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34457784/how-to-put-elements-to-same-row