# How to put elements to same row

Tags: css, html

html5 order print form below is created from existing template which contains fixed layout fields.
Every field appears in separate row:

[image: separate]

How do I fix this so that the fields appear in the same row? I tried to fix it by using absolute position:

```
    .horizontalline, .field {
        position: absolute;
    }
```

In this case, elements appear is some rows properly but the stretched product description field overwrites the next row product name field:

[image: o]

How to fix this?
Attributes, style can be changed. It is possible to add additional elements.

Html basics structure (row element contains 0 or 1 field element) should preferably probably not changed since there is no better way to render absolutely positioned separate fields from existing non-html template.

Testcase:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .row {
      position: relative;
      clear: both;
    }
    .field {
      overflow: hidden;
      word-break: break-all;
    }
    .horizontalline {
      font-size: 1pt;
      border: 1px solid #000000;
    }
    .horizontalline,
    .field {
      position: relative;
    }
    .horizontalline {
      border-bottom-style: none !important;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class='row' style='min-height:0.05cm;'>
    <div class='horizontalline' style='left:1.11cm;width:19.05cm;height:0.00cm;border-color:#C0C0C0;'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
    <div class='field' style='left:1.26cm;width:0.71cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;color:#000000;'>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
    <div class='field' style='left:2.05cm;width:8.47cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;color:#000000;'>HP ProDesk 490 G3 - Micro tower - 1 x Core i7 6700</div>
  </div>
  <div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
    <div class='field' style='left:10.58cm;width:1.68cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;text-align:right;color:#000000;'>31.12.2015</div>
  </div>
  <div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
    <div class='field' style='left:12.24cm;width:0.79cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;text-align:right;color:#000000;'>1</div>
  </div>
  <div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
    <div class='field' style='left:13.08cm;width:1.08cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;color:#000000;'>tk</div>
  </div>
  <div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
    <div class='field' style='left:14.32cm;width:1.26cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;color:#000000;'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
  </div>
  <div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
    <div class='field' style='left:16.61cm;width:1.42cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;text-align:right;color:#000000;'>1189</div>
  </div>
  <div class='row' style='min-height:0.42cm;'>
    <div class='field' style='left:17.79cm;width:2.00cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;font-weight:bold;text-align:right;color:#000000;'>1189</div>

  </div>
  <div class='row' style='min-height:0.51cm;'>
    <div class='field' style='left:2.24cm;width:9.79cm;min-height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;color:#000000;'>RAM 16 GB - SSD 256 GB - DVD SuperMulti - GF GT 730M / HD Graphics 530 - GigE - Windows 7 Professional 64-bit Edition / Windows 10 Pro 64-bit Edition downgrade - pre-installed: Windows 7</div>

  </div>

  <div class='row' style='min-height:0.05cm;'>
    <div class='horizontalline' style='left:1.11cm;width:19.05cm;height:0.00cm;border-color:#C0C0C0;'></div>

  </div>
  <div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
    <div class='field' style='left:1.26cm;width:0.71cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;color:#000000;'>2</div>


  </div>
  <div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
    <div class='field' style='left:2.05cm;width:8.47cm;min-height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;color:#000000;'>24x7 monitor: LG 32SL5B</div>


  </div>
  <div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
    <div class='field' style='left:10.58cm;width:1.68cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;text-align:right;color:#000000;'>29.12.2015</div>


  </div>
  <div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
    <div class='field' style='left:12.24cm;width:0.79cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;text-align:right;color:#000000;'>3</div>


  </div>
  <div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
    <div class='field' style='left:13.08cm;width:1.08cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;color:#000000;'>tk</div>

  </div>
  <div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
    <div class='field' style='left:14.32cm;width:1.26cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;color:#000000;'>878,79</div>

  </div>
  <div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>

  </div>
  <div class='row' style='min-height:0.00cm;'>
    <div class='field' style='left:16.61cm;width:1.42cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;text-align:right;color:#000000;'>580</div>

  </div>
  <div class='row' style='min-height:0.42cm;'>
    <div class='field' style='left:17.79cm;width:2.00cm;height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;font-weight:bold;text-align:right;color:#000000;'>1740</div>

  </div>
  <div class='row' style='min-height:0.51cm;'>
    <div class='field' style='left:2.24cm;width:9.79cm;min-height:0.42cm;z-Index:2;font-family:Arial;font-size:8pt;color:#000000;'>450cd/m2, HDMI / DP / DVI / RGB / RJ45 /etc, 24/7 Operation, laos</div>

  </div>
  <div class='row' style='min-height:0.05cm;'>
    <div class='horizontalline' style='left:1.11cm;width:19.05cm;height:0.00cm;border-color:#C0C0C0;'></div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Would you call this MCVE?

Comment: Isn't this the same question from 4 hours ago? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34455552/how-to-force-div-to-appear-after-streche-div

Comment: Yes, this is complete and minimal example. It can saved to file and opened in desktop Chrome.

Comment: Well you could do that in a JSFiddle or Stack Snippet...couldn't you?

Comment: @Paulie_D This is different. This question assumes that relative layout and c min-height are applied. Question you referenced asks about different ways for it.

Comment: @Paulie_D Question is refactored to use code snippet

Comment: I'm not even going to touch a codedump with **that much inline CSS** .....if you extract it to a stylesheet in a Fiddle or Snippet it might be feasible. Frankly, this looks like a job for a table.

Comment: @Paulie_D You can press **Run code snippet button** in question. Orders can sent by email or saved separately, inline style should used. Layout should created from aready exising non-html templates having absolute positioned elements. Every field cas positioned in different position. Tables cannot solve this

Comment: @Amit Question is updated and runnable code snipped is added

Comment: Please read [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Amit I have read this. Code snippet in question conforms to it.

Comment: Perhaps you don't understand it then. **Minimal** means there's nothing that can be removed without breaking the code. Also, if you read all of [ask] and inner links, you'd know questions should strive to be general, not specific. No future reader cares about your particular data. Use the minimum markup required to show a version of your problem.

Comment: @Amit Layout description is created using GUI report designer by end users. They can put field to any position in canvas, there is no structure. So **inline styles must used**. Testcase clearly reflects this. Queston asks for changing some particular fields. It is not about best practices, This is clearly written. Please change your downvote to upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I recommend reading up on some basic HTML, tables specifically.
To display elements in a line without any changes in the html there are 2 approaches:

1. `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;` (`inline-block` makes the element appear in a line while keeping the benefits of a block level element)
2. `float: left;`

Both of the CSS rules have to be applied to all the elements you want to display in a row, preferrably by a rather specific selector like `.list-element` which would target all elements with the class *list-element* or `#mylist > div` which targets all `div` elements that are direct descendants of the element with id `mylist`.

Comment: There are existing layouts with contain hard-coded field position and sizes.  Every field may apper in different position. html print form should created from those layouts. Answer describes best practices to create new layout. Question states that already exising layout should used. So this answer does not apply to question. How to fix testcase in question, maybe there is simple fix ?

Comment: Use a `<table>` or display the elements inline as I explained. What else do you want to know, if neither a HTML nor a CSS approach helps?

Answer (score 2):

To start using the Flexbox model, you need to first define a flex container.

Set the justify-content property to center, and the flex item will be centered:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
```